# Variable Not Setting Properly On DIV Resize - Additional Information Added

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var globaltest = 400;
$('.Quick-Sidebar-Toggle').click(function() {

    var QSWSW = $(".Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper").width() == globaltest ? "0" : globaltest;
    alert(globaltest + ", " + QSWSW);

    $('.Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper').animate({
       width: QSWSW + "px"
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    });

});

$('.Quick-Sidebar').bind('resize', function(e) {
    globaltest = $(this).width();
});
```

The variable is changing upon DIV resize via a test I implemented;

```
$('.PannelLogo').click(function(e) {
    alert(globaltest);
});
```

However upon checking upon clicking to toggle the quick access side panel once again via;

```
alert(globaltest + ', ' + QSWSW);
```

If I haven't resized it will say '400, 0' however if I do resize it will say the pixel value of the width twice ie '520, 520'

Attempted a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4L153j1g/) but didn't work... You can see the live version [here](http://rafflebananza.com/Admin/Desktop/index2.html) where you can click the red square in the top-right corner to open, see the alert, resize, click the logo to see what the variable is however upon clicking to hide again, the variable which is shown in the alert is wrong...

### Update I

Basically upon resize my script sets `globaltest` so for `var QSWSW = $(".Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper").width() == globaltest ? "0" : globaltest;` it basically means if width is not 0 then it should be and visa versa for opening it back up.

This works if you **don't** resize however doesn't if you **do** resize...

### Update II

I'm still not near solving this problem and have tried several dozen attempts including the following;

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar-Toggle').click(function() {

    if (QSWSCW == globaltest) {
        QSWSW = 0;
    } else {
        QSWSW = globaltest;
    }

    $('.Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper').animate({
       width: 'toggle'
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    });

});
```

Comment: could you reproduce in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Pamblam Just tried [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4L153j1g/) but didn't work... You can see the live version [here](http://rafflebananza.com/Admin/Desktop/index2.html)

Comment: the variables in the alert are correct. tell us what you were expecting to happen and we can tell you why it's not happening.

Comment: `var QSWSW = $(".Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper").width() == globaltest ? "0" : globaltest;` This does not work, if it is open, and you resize, it does not say 0. Try opening up the quick side panel, resizing and then closing on the live version please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You don't need to predefine the width:

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar-Toggle').click(function() {

    $('.Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper').animate({
       width: 'toggle'
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutBounce'
    });

});
```

### ...Just toggle it!